# debug feature activation

Tags: 2013, feature-activation, debugging

I have a visual studio project with Sharepoint Site structure. I **didn't** write any Event Receivers that will add my items (SP List Definitions, List Instances, ...) to the site. That means I use ERs included in generated by Visual Studio **.wsp**. 
When I extend SP items, or add new ones, from time to time I get "Error in feature activation" exception. I need some kind of debug to find out source(name, title, url,...) of item I did wrong. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just look in the ULS logs

Comment: Robert, ULS details level ends with Feature Id. I want more details, cause I have all site lists in that single feature

Comment: You can always debug the Event Receivers if you think that is where it is failing. Just hook up to w3wp if activating from the browser, and powershell / sptimerv4 if feature activation from powershell / solution installation from powershell.